# squid3 proxy filter

Tags: squid

I am a network manager and I have a proxy squid factor and the prohibition of some sites such as YouTube and Facebook through the filter to use the proxy when I was a broken program psiphon3 that left open the site how to prevent this program

Comment: Please help us help you: try to explain yourself a little more. Your question's wording is hard to understand.  Tx

Comment: How you can stop the program psiphon3 from opening blocked sites through proxy squid

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you install the program psiphon3 and analyze yours squid `access.log`.

Once installed, begin to make requests to sites that you have allowed.

I block such sites, such as you-freedom, using various techniques, some of which result has given me more is to block the IPs in the url:

```
# Restrict navegation by IP
acl ip_restriction dstdom_regex ^(([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)|(\[([0-9af]+)?:([0-9af:]+)?:([0-9af]+)?\]))
http_access deny ip_restriction
```

you can also add rules for patterns:

```
# Pattern Block, for example, proxy anonymous, so on.
acl patterns_urls url_regex -i "/etc/squid3/acl_files/patterns_urls"
http_access deny patterns_urls
```

That's just an idea of how I would block. I will present the program psiphon3 block it.